# How to implement sign out function in the new navigation drawer in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, navigation-drawer

I would like to implement the sign out method in my project. i watch all youtube tutorial but seems like the navigation drawer is the update version. and i'm clueless on how to implement those sign out coding into my coding.

the newest version of the navigation drawer already built in with the ui package folder. So i'm not quite sure on how to implement those tutorial code  because most of the tutorial code have this code.
 below is the tutorial code and i don't know on how to implement the sign out method into my home.java code. thank you

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new HomeFragment()).commit();

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {

                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Profile");
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new ProfileFragment()).commit();

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new SettingsFragment()).commit();


            }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_signout) {

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent loginActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginActivity);
                finish();


            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
```

this is my home.java code

```
package com.example.guru;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        //ini
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer");


        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_orders,R.id.nav_logout)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();



        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);



        updateNavHeader();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    public void updateNavHeader() {
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View headerView= navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView navName= headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        TextView navEmail=headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

        navName.setText(currentUser.getDisplayName());
        navEmail.setText(currentUser.getEmail());

    }
}
```

LogoutFragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.guru.R;

public class LogoutFragment extends Fragment {

    private LogoutViewModel logoutViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        logoutViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LogoutViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_logout, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_logout);

        logoutViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

and this is my LogoutViewModel

```
package com.example.guru.ui.Logout;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class LogoutViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public LogoutViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("logout");
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **200** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: In the meanwhile, you can take a look at a [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp) of mine in which I have implemented Navigation Drawer together with the sign-out function and clean arhitecture. Might solve your problem. You can also take a look at **[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esYPwbGW7YY)** .

Answer (score 30):

Feels like there should be a built in solution but so far I have solved it like this.
I simply add a click listener on that menu option, in my case my logout button:

In Java -->

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setOnMenuItemClickListener(menuItem -> {
    logout();
    return true;
});
```

In Kotlin -->

```
navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_logout).setOnMenuItemClickListener({ menuItem ->
                logoutDialog()
                true
            })
```

Comment: OMG, lifesaver, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found two solution to handle it.

**1. If you have register your fragment in navigation graph than**

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.logout){
                    logout();
                }
            }
        });
```

**2. If you don't have register fragment in navigation graph and you just want to handle click event on drawer menu.**

```
mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_logout).setOnMenuItemClickListener(menuItem -> {
            AppUtils.showLongToast("this works", getApplicationContext());
            return true;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

my navigation menu code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:title="@string/menu_share" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:title="Logout" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:title="Login" />
</menu>
```

code inside onResume method , this will hide either sign out or sign in button depending upon auth state of user

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(false);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.login).setVisible(true);
            // perform action when user is not logged in
        } else {
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(true);
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.login).setVisible(false);
            // perform action when user is already logged in
        }

    }
```

Handle navigation view item clicks here.

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.logout) {
        auth.signOut();
        onResume();
    } else if (id == R.id.login) {
        //handle event login button pressed 
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: You can try explaining the issue, rather giving direct code snippet.

Comment: where should i implement those code ? should i put it inside my home.java class? the issues here is i don't know where to implement the sign out code, because all the tutorial i follow inside the youtube has a different navigation drawer code. Hopefully u understand what im trying to say :)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with the help of constraint layout

[image]